# Can you apply a attribute to multiple fields in C#?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

This doesn't seem possible, but I'll ask anyway... Is it possible in C# to apply a single attribute to multiple fields at once?

```
public class MyClass {
     [SomeAttribute]
     public int m_nVar1;
     [SomeAttribute]
     public int m_nVar2;
     public int m_nVar3;
}
```

Is there a short-hand method to put the "SomeAttribute" on m_Var1 & m_Var2, but not on m_nVar3? Currently, we are placing the attributes before each field, but it would be nice to put all the fields using a attribute inside a block.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's possible:

```
[SomeAttribute]
public int m_nVar1, m_nVar2;
```

(but obviously only if the types are the same)

Comment: Yeah, Thanks.. but the types certainly won't be the same in our use case.

Comment: @Faustus Where the types differ, there is no way of doing this.

Comment: Ok, thanks... that's what I figured since I couldn't find it in MSDN in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This could work?, but might end up being pretty tedious

```
public class CustomClass
{
 [CustomAttribute]
 public dynamic value { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public CustomClass m_nVar1, var2, var3;
    public MyClass()
    {
        m_nVar1.value = (int)m_nVar1.value;
        var2.value = (string)var2.value;
    }
}
```