# Applying a C# attribute to many fields

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a minimal C# class that looks like the following:

```
class Thing
{
    private float a, b, c, d;
    (...)
}
```

Is there a way that I can apply an attribute to *all four* fields without having to write it out four times?  If I put `[SomeAttribute]` in front of the `private`, it appears to apply to `a` only.

Comment: Possible repeated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725998/can-you-apply-a-attribute-to-multiple-fields-in-c

Comment: Why not just declare each variable separately?

Comment: If you end up writing it out fully, use Alt+Shift+Down 4 times first. It will select 4 lines and clone what you type, save you actually typing it 4 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
[SomeAttribute]
public int m_nVar1, m_nVar2;
```

(but obviously only if the types are the same)

**[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725998/can-you-apply-a-attribute-to-multiple-fields-in-c)**

Example:

```
[ContextStatic]
private float a, b, c, d;
```

Comment: You could, of course, include that you copied this verbatim from [romkyn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726024/146622).

Comment: It is better to post link instead of copying the entire answer. See this discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions

Comment: You're right of course.  I thought it only applied to the first one, but I was misinterpreting an error message from the compiler.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Thing
{
    [SomeAttribute]
    public float a, b, c, d;
}
```

The above, which you proposed, would work how you expect it to work. You can test this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
sealed class SomeAttribute: Attribute
{
    public SomeAttribute()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = typeof(Thing);
        var attrs = from f in t.GetFields()
                    from a in f.GetCustomAttributes()
                    select new { Name = f.Name, Attribute = a.GetType() };

        foreach (var a in attrs)
            Console.WriteLine(a.Name + ": " + a.Attribute);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
a: SomeAttribute
b: SomeAttribute
c: SomeAttribute
d: SomeAttribute
```

Comment: You're right, thanks.  I misinterpreted an error message from elsewhere in my project :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can acheive that in any way using visual studio.

The least annoying way i can think of, is to use [MultiEdit](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimultaneousEditingForVisualStudioWithTheFreeMultiEditExtension.aspx) where you can place multiple cursors, and only write the attribute once.